# Unity Trigger Loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, triggers

what I want to do in my project is to play the animation and make the text visible when the character enters a trigger and presses the "E" key. I do this but when I exit the trigger and re-enter and press the "E" key again, it doesn't play the animation. I would be glad if you could help. Here is my code ->

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    text.enabled = false;
}


void Update()
{
    if(text.enabled = true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.Play("LeverUpDown");
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    text.enabled = false;                                                                                                                                           
 }
```

}

Comment: you are missing a = if(text.enabled == true && ....)

Comment: Also please [**debug**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) this yourself and check if the conditions are fulfilled when you expect them to be ...

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the animation already play when you re-enter that trigger,
try to put
`anim.Stop();`
after
`text.enabled = false;`

Comment: I only had to connect it to the empty state to repeat it because the animation is played on the animator controller. Thanks for your help.